# Formatting issue with c++ Can someone help me?

Tags: c++, formatting

i am new here and trying to write code in c++. 
I have a formatting issue with the day 1 in my program, can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Here are the assignment details.

For this assignment, write a program that will calculate how much a person would earn over a finite (random) period of time if his/her salary is a random amount for the first day and continues to double each day.

So if a person's starting salary is $0.04, they would earn that $0.04 for the first day of work, $0.08 for the second day of work, $0.16 for the third day of work, etc.... Over three days, the person would earn $0.28.

If the example is carried on for a few more days, the person would earn $0.32 for the fourth day, a total of $1.04 ($0.64 in salary and a $0.40 bonus) for the fifth day, and $1.28 for the sixth day, resulting in a total of $2.92 for 6 days of work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()


{

srand(1);

srand(time(0));


    float salary = 0, bonus = 0, totalpay = 0;
    int days = 0, salary2;

salary = rand() % 6 + 1;
salary = salary / 100;
days = rand() % 31;
totalpay = salary;

    cout << "Starting salary: " << salary << endl
         << "Days worked: " << days << endl
         << "************************************" << endl
         << setw(30) << "Daily Salary" << setw(30) << "Amount Earned" << setw(30) << endl;

    for (int d = 0; d < days; d++)
    {

        cout << "Day " << d + 1 << ":" << '\t'
        << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(18) << salary << '\t'
        << setw(18)<< (totalpay+bonus) << endl;

        salary *= 2;

        if ((d+1) % 5 == 0)
            bonus = salary * 10;
        else
            bonus = 0.00;

        totalpay += salary;



    }



return 0;        

    enter code here

}
```

*****This is my output****

```
Starting salary: 0.02
Days worked: 20
************************************
                  Daily Salary                 Amount Earned
                          Day 1:                      0.02                    0.
02
Day 2:                0.04                    0.06
Day 3:                0.08                    0.14
Day 4:                0.16                    0.30
Day 5:                0.32                    0.62
Day 6:                0.64                    7.66
Day 7:                1.28                    2.54
Day 8:                2.56                    5.10
Day 9:                5.12                   10.22
Day 10:              10.24                   20.46
Day 11:              20.48                  245.74
Day 12:              40.96                   81.90
Day 13:              81.92                  163.82
Day 14:             163.84                  327.66
Day 15:             327.68                  655.34
Day 16:             655.36                 7864.30
Day 17:            1310.72                 2621.42
Day 18:            2621.44                 5242.86
Day 19:            5242.88                10485.74
Day 20:           10485.76                20971.50

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.1105 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: If you are having an output problem you need to show the expected output and the output you are getting.

Comment: Thank you, i fixed my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change:

```
-         << setw(30) << "Daily Salary" << setw(30) << "Amount Earned" << setw(30) << endl;
+         << setw(30) << "Daily Salary" << setw(30) << "Amount Earned" << endl;
```

The last `setw(30)` before the `endl` is being applied to the next piece of text, in your case to the `"Day "` in the first iteration.

Comment: Thank you! You fixed it!

Comment: @BradleyTourt throw Jose a bone and mark this as the answer. Jose, I recommend filling this out a bit more so it doesn't get deleted for being a code-only answer. Add what you did, why, and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your code...

```
     << setw(30) << "Daily Salary" << setw(30) << "Amount Earned" << setw(30) << endl;

for (int d = 0; d < days; d++)
{
    cout << "Day " << d + 1 << ":" << '\t'
```

The `setw(30)` right before `endl;` is applying to `"Day "`, not the `endl`. You can't use `setw` for `endl`.